# python comand to schedule time window between 12.00h and 13.30h

Tags: python

I would like to program a script the does the following;

if during the time 12.00h and 13.30h a input is high, it should execute the script.

if the input is high and the the time is outside 12.00h-13.30h the script should not execut.
I tryed it with the following code, but it does not work, what is the solution??

```
   #!/usr/bin/python



import datetime
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
import pifacedigitalio
from time import sleep
pfd = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital() # creates a PiFace Digital object
testprocess = None
now = datetime.datetime.now()

if now.hour == 12 or (now.hour == 13 and now.minute <= 30):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

    if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 1 and not testprocess:
        sleep(2)
        subprocess.Popen(["/bin/myscript"])
        sleep(5)
        testprocess = Popen(["/bin/myscriptxy"])

        if pfd.input_pins[0].value == 0:
            if testprocess:
               testprocess.kill()
               testprocess = None
               sleep(5)
               subprocess.Popen(["/bin/myscript"])
        sleep(1)
```

Comment: You do realize that your placement of the `if pfd.input_pins...` bit is in the `else` branch, right? Which means that it will execute only *outside* your desired time period...

Comment: Thanks, now it works.

Comment: How do I change the time   from                                                                        if now.hour == 6 or (now.hour == 8 and now.minute <= 30):
to  between   6:30 and 8:00h

Answer (score 1):

datetime.datetime is *way* more convenient than working with strftime.

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if now.hour == 12 or (now.hour == 13 and now.minute <= 30):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Hello, I inserted your code but it is not working can you please check it an correct it. Thanks.

Comment: I might be tempted to add `nowtag = now.hour * 100 + now.minute` so that the condition could then just be `if 1200 <= nowtag < 1330`. But that doesn't  significantly change the functionality - it's just a visual nicety I've used in the past...

Comment: When I start the script in the command line it always shows false.

Comment: I corrected the time window from 16.30h until 22.30. still shows allways false. Can you please insert the correct code in my first post? Thanks

Comment: @twalberg I actually like the idea, but it's much clearer whats going on without it. :)

Comment: @user3804654 no i won't fix your code for you. I provided a very easy (and working with 2.7 and 3.5) code snippet. If you'r still unable to fix this yourself you should consider to hire someone who can instead of asking the same question over and over again on stackoverflow.